# How to properly cancel an asynchronous and running method if it is invoked again and the previous invokation result is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, design-patterns, cancellation

I have a rather generic question but with a specific use case.

In my specific case I have a UI with an input text box and if the user is changing the text in  that input box some recommendations are shown to what the user might want to type in eventually. In other words the input box uses an autocomplete feature. The recommendations are requested from a webservice, hence this process takes a significant amount of time in  which  the user  might already changed the text again. Hence, I want to cancel or stop the process that is still acquiring obsolete data and only take the results of the most recent invocation of the method.

So imagine a method `OnTextChanged` in the View class that is calling the method `GetRecommendationsAsync`. My approach is to simply cancel the previous and obsolete invokation  of `GetRecommendationsAsync` and then don't do anything in the UI if the method is canceled. Here some minimal code I just wrote up (so could contain errors) to show the concept:

```
public async Task OnTextChangedAsync(string newText)
{
    try
    {
        var recommendations = await GetLatestRecommendationsAsync(newText);
        ShowRecommendations(recommendations);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException)
    {
    }
}

private Task<Recommendations[]> GetLatestRecommendationsAsync(string text)
{
     _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
     _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) return null;

     return GetRecommendationsAsync(text, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Now, my question is if this is a valid approach or does it have some shortcommings?
Furthermore, I would like to know if there is a general known pattern to handle the generic case of cancelling a method that is obsolete because it was called again?
Is an appraoch using a semaphore better? 
How would you approach this case?
Is it guaranteed that the cancellation of the previous invocation is caught before the new invocation returns its results?

Comment: It seems valid to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would like to know if there is a general known pattern to handle the generic case of cancelling a method that is obsolete because it was called again?

Cancellation tokens are the general known pattern to handle cancelling for *any* reason.

> Is it guaranteed that the cancellation of the previous invocation is caught before the new invocation returns its results?

No. This is because cancellation tokens are for cooperative cancellation, meaning that one side *requests* cancellation, and the other side periodically checks for a cancellation request and decides how to cancel. The purpose of this approach is to make sure that anything that needs undoing is undone, and you aren't leaving things in an unstable state.

Contrast that with, say, doing work in a background thread and just killing the thread to cancel. You have no idea at what point it was killed and if anything has been left in a potentially unknown or unstable state.

If, for whatever reason, you have to make sure you don't even *start* another attempt until the previous one is known to be stopped, then you would have to use something like a semaphore (maybe along with a cancellation token). That all depends on what `GetRecommendationsAsync` is doing.

A side note: the signature of `OnTextChangedAsync` looks suspicious. It's named like an event, but events must return `void`.

Comment: Good explanation. You can’t just go around canceling other code that is already running.